# Unable to grab certain links from dynamic content

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to scrape the links of different properties located at the right sided area right next to the map from its landing page.

***[Link to the landing page](https://www.zillow.com/homes/33155_rb/)***

When I click on each block manually from chrome I see links containing this `/for_sale/` portion in a new tab whereas what my script fetches contain `/homedetails/`.

***How can I get the number of results (such as 153 homes for sale) along with right links to the properties?***

My try so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/33155_rb/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)

itemcount = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#map-result-count-message h2")))
print(itemcount.text)

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".zsg-photo-card-overlay-link"))):
    print(item.get_attribute("href"))
driver.quit()
```

One of the current output:

```
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/6860-SW-48th-Ter-Miami-FL-33155/44206318_zpid/
```

One of such expected output:

```
https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Miami-FL-33155/house_type/44184455_zpid/72458_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/25.776783,-80.256072,25.695446,-80.364905_rect/12_zm/0_mmm/
```

Comment: As for itemcount, I believe it is populated after page is loaded, so you need some kind of delay/sleep for that.

As for incorrect links, you have css selector that gets links with homedetails, so just change it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While analyzing /homedetails/ and /for_sale/ links, I found that /homedetails/ link usually contains some sort of code like this:

> 44206318_zpid

that code acts as a unique identifier for the ad post, I extracted it and added it to:

> https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/

so the final link for the ad post will be like this:

> https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/**44206318_zpid**

It's a valid link and takes to the AD post.

Here is the final script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/33155_rb/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)

itemcount = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#map-result-count-message h2")))
print(itemcount.text)

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".zsg-photo-card-overlay-link"))):
    link = item.get_attribute("href")
    if "zpid" in link:
        print("https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/{}".format(link.split('/')[-2]))
```

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the pagination `div`s and keep a running counter of the number of homes displayed on each page. To parse the `html`, this answer utilizes `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re, time
def home_num(_d:soup) -> int:
  return len(_d.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('^/homedetails/')}))

d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.zillow.com/homes/33155_rb/')
homecount, _links = home_num(soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')), []
_seen_links, _result_links = [], []
_start = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') if isinstance(i.get_attribute("href"), str) and re.findall('/homes/for_sale/', i.get_attribute("href")) and i.get_attribute("href") not in _seen_links]
while _start:
  _new_start = _start[0]
  try:
     _new_start.send_keys('\n')
     time.sleep(5)
     _start = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') if isinstance(i.get_attribute("href"), str) and re.findall('/homes/for_sale/', i.get_attribute("href")) and i.get_attribute("href") not in _seen_links]
  except:
    _seen_links.append(_new_start.get_attribute('href'))
    _start = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') if isinstance(i.get_attribute("href"), str) and re.findall('/homes/for_sale/', i.get_attribute("href")) and i.get_attribute("href") not in _seen_links]
  else:
     _seen_links.append(_new_start.get_attribute('href'))
     _result_links.append(_new_start.get_attribute('href'))
     homecount += home_num(soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser'))
```

Comment: Your script throws an error `stale element reference:` when it hits the line just before the while loop @Ajax1234.

Answer (score 0):

> If you inspect those images present at right hand side of the page you will see "homedetails" not "forsale".
>   Just try to open link in new tab and observe the actuallink is "homedetails".

Comment: The links I'm talking about are not in the source. They get generated dynamically in a new tab upon clicking on each container @rishav prasher.